# Updating pandas via conda on Sagemaker EXTREMELY slow

Tags: python, pandas, conda, amazon-sagemaker

Sagemaker default python environments hosted in my work environment have outdated pandas, and therefore must have their conda environment updated.  However, this is incredibly slow (15-30 mins), and I would like to find a faster way to get a working environment

I update with the following:

```
!conda update pandas fsspec --yes
```

Which gives the following output, with the key problem being an inconsistent starting environment (How?) as shown by
`failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done`

output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/linux-64::pandas==1.0.1=py36h0573a6f_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab==1.2.6=pyhf63ae98_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scikit-learn==0.22.1=py36hd81dba3_0
  - defaults/linux-64::python-language-server==0.31.7=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bkcharts==0.2=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nb_conda==2.2.1=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::numpydoc==0.9.2=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pytest-arraydiff==0.3=py36h39e3cac_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bottleneck==1.3.2=py36heb32a55_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pywavelets==1.1.1=py36h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/noarch::pytest-astropy==0.8.0=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numexpr==2.7.1=py36h423224d_0
  - defaults/noarch::anaconda-project==0.8.4=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::boto3==1.9.162=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::s3transfer==0.2.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nbconvert==5.6.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::h5py==2.10.0=py36h7918eee_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bokeh==1.4.0=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==1.0.6=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numpy-base==1.18.1=py36hde5b4d6_1
  - defaults/noarch::botocore==1.12.189=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py36_7
  - defaults/linux-64::astropy==4.0=py36h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::patsy==0.5.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scikit-image==0.16.2=py36h0573a6f_0
  - defaults/linux-64::matplotlib-base==3.1.3=py36hef1b27d_0
  - defaults/linux-64::imageio==2.6.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pytables==3.6.1=py36h71ec239_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nb_conda_kernels==2.2.4=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl_fft==1.0.15=py36ha843d7b_0
  - defaults/linux-64::statsmodels==0.11.0=py36h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::spyder==4.0.1=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::seaborn==0.10.0=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::requests==2.22.0=py36_1
  - defaults/linux-64::numba==0.48.0=py36h0573a6f_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scipy==1.4.1=py36h0b6359f_0
  - defaults/noarch::pytest-doctestplus==0.5.0=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl_random==1.1.0=py36hd6b4f25_0
  - defaults/noarch::dask==2.11.0=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.5.1=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::s3fs==0.4.2=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::notebook==6.0.3=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::matplotlib==3.1.3=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numpy==1.18.1=py36h4f9e942_0
failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab==1.2.6=pyhf63ae98_0
  - defaults/linux-64::python-language-server==0.31.7=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nb_conda==2.2.1=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::numpydoc==0.9.2=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::anaconda-project==0.8.4=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::boto3==1.9.162=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::s3transfer==0.2.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nbconvert==5.6.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::bokeh==1.4.0=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_server==1.0.6=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::botocore==1.12.189=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py36_7
  - defaults/linux-64::scikit-image==0.16.2=py36h0573a6f_0
  - defaults/linux-64::imageio==2.6.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nb_conda_kernels==2.2.4=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::spyder==4.0.1=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::requests==2.22.0=py36_1
  - defaults/noarch::dask==2.11.0=py_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.5.1=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py36_0
  - defaults/noarch::s3fs==0.4.2=py_0
  - defaults/linux-64::notebook==6.0.3=py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::anaconda-client==1.7.2=py36_0
done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.8.4
  latest version: 4.9.2

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3

  added / updated specs:
    - fsspec
    - pandas
    - s3fs


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    astroid-2.4.2              |   py36h9f0ad1d_1         297 KB  conda-forge
    certifi-2020.12.5          |   py36h5fab9bb_1         143 KB  conda-forge
    docutils-0.16              |   py36h5fab9bb_3         738 KB  conda-forge
    pandas-1.1.4               |   py36hd87012b_0        10.5 MB  conda-forge
    pillow-7.1.2               |   py36hb39fc2d_0         604 KB
    pylint-2.6.0               |   py36h9f0ad1d_1         446 KB  conda-forge
    sphinx-3.4.3               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         1.5 MB  conda-forge
    toml-0.10.2                |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          18 KB  conda-forge
    urllib3-1.25.11            |             py_0          93 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        14.3 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  astroid            conda-forge/linux-64::astroid-2.4.2-py36h9f0ad1d_1
  bleach             conda-forge/noarch::bleach-3.2.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  brotlipy           conda-forge/linux-64::brotlipy-0.7.0-py36he6145b8_1001
  docutils           conda-forge/linux-64::docutils-0.16-py36h5fab9bb_3
  pillow             pkgs/main/linux-64::pillow-7.1.2-py36hb39fc2d_0
  pylint             conda-forge/linux-64::pylint-2.6.0-py36h9f0ad1d_1
  sphinx             conda-forge/noarch::sphinx-3.4.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  toml               conda-forge/noarch::toml-0.10.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  urllib3            conda-forge/noarch::urllib3-1.25.11-py_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates                      2020.11.8-ha878542_0 --> 2020.12.5-ha878542_0
  certifi                          2020.11.8-py36h5fab9bb_0 --> 2020.12.5-py36h5fab9bb_1
  fsspec                       pkgs/main::fsspec-0.6.2-py_0 --> conda-forge::fsspec-0.8.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  pandas             pkgs/main::pandas-1.0.1-py36h0573a6f_0 --> conda-forge::pandas-1.1.4-py36hd87012b_0



Downloading and Extracting Packages
pillow-7.1.2         | 604 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
astroid-2.4.2        | 297 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
pylint-2.6.0         | 446 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
sphinx-3.4.3         | 1.5 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
pandas-1.1.4         | 10.5 MB   | ##################################### | 100% 
docutils-0.16        | 738 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
urllib3-1.25.11      | 93 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
certifi-2020.12.5    | 143 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
toml-0.10.2          | 18 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Happy to take any suggestions for  how to get a python notebook up in sagemaker as quickly as possible with modern packages.

Other attempted solutions:

- a fast `pip install -U` doesn't work due to dependency issues -- the
  local environment in the notebook will try to point pandas to
  outdated fsspec and it will crash
- Following AWS documentation for adding my conda requests to the startup script doesn't work because there is a timeout on the startup script (10 mins I think?) so a 15+ minute `conda update` process just ensures the sagemaker instance cannot start

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is because conda does a dependencies checks. It tries to find the version of the package which is compatible with all packages while pip install the required package and it's dependencies which might result with inconsistency. [[1]](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip)

There are two workarounds for this issue,

1. Creating a custom environment with the required packages and create a kernel to be used from Sagemaker notebook.
2. Using the --no-deps option `pip install pandas==<version> --no-deps`. You might need to use the `-U` option.

To recap, I would suggest either creating a custom environment or using pip to install the package and all it's dependencies with the option `--no-deps`. You might need to try both approaches while the notebook is running and then apply to the lifecycle configurations script.